# How can I get current localization of Linux through C?

Tags: c, linux, locale

How can I get current localization (ru-RU, en-US, en-GB, e.t.c.) of Linux through C?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

On a POSIX-compliant system, `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL);` would return the name of the locale currently selected for category `LC_CTYPE`.

Comment: I have tried such code:

`#include<stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
 char *c = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL);
 
 if (NULL == c)
  printf("Can't get localization.");
 else
  printf("Current Localization: %s\n", c);
 
 return 0;
}`

but I got this: **Current Localization: C**. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Notice that `"C"` (or `"POSIX"`) is an acceptable localization; it it the default one, if nothing has set it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [nl_langinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nl_langinfo) and the 
[localeconv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localeconv) man pages.

How to search for subroutines and/or system calls on a Unix system:

- query via apropos.
  e.g.: `apropos locale`
- look for results which reference man section 2 (system calls) or man section 3. (subroutines).
  e.g. on mac:

  > ```
  > querylocale(3)           - Get locale name for a specified category
  > setlocale(3)             - natural language formatting for C
  > ```
- have a look at the man pages